# Properly scripting onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Google Sheets file with 3 spreadsheets. Each of the first 2 contains numerous number data entries.  All I want to do is change one cell value on the third (tt) if any data is changed on a different sheet. Looking at my incomplete onEdit() script, you will see I obviously don’t know what I’m doing.  How  to I change the value of cell ‘a5’ on third spreadsheet (tt) for any changes made anywhere on only the first two?

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var aa = event.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Input-Expenses");
  var ss = event.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Input-Income-n-Assets");
  var tt = event.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Run Program");
  var r = event.aa.getActiveRange('a1:r105');
  var s = event.ss.getActiveRange('d1:q94');
  var g =  0
  tt.getRange('a5').setValue(g);  
}
```

Comment: Please checkout [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to this article:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Find Edit trigger.

> **range**  A Range object, representing the cell or range of cells that
>   were edited.

Usage:

```
var editedRange = event.range; 
var editedSheet = editedRange.getSheet();
if (editedSheet.getName() === 'Sheet1')
{
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  // do smth
}
```

Comment: You can lose the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` with `e.source`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want

```
function onEdit(event) {
  try {
    var aName = event.range.getSheet().getName();  // Active sheet
    if( ( aName === "Input-Expenses" ) || ( aName === "Input-Income-n-Assets" ) ) {
      // You said anywhere on these 2 sheets and put in Run Program:A5
      event.source.getSheetByName("Run Program").getRange("A5").setValue(0);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```